# Sending packets to another website when a button was clicked

Tags: html

[image: text file that I wanted to show be shown]I am trying to build my first version of my website and want to add some features to it. So, I want to take portion of some website and take it to my website to presented to visitor of my website. To make it clear, I want to show the text field on https://asked.kr/yeramy onto my website, so with click of a button, it will send request packet with question in it. Thereby, I can answer the question through the http://asked.kr.

Comment: Can you be more specific here? What have you tried so far? What issues have you run into?

Comment: As you might have seen it or not, there is text field on the website that I referenced. which looks like the picture added. I am not sure of how to take that text field onto one of component of my website.

Comment: An iframe could be an easy solution. For anything more, you have to tell us who is sending what, how, and where the requests go. Is it same domain, different domains, who controls the recipient end?

Comment: you just resolved it. thank you so much. I didn't know about Iframe